# Old django template

Tags: django

I have been using a django project template, django-html5-boilerplate, that works with Django 1.5. Would it be workable to use it with 1.6, or does a django project template have to be version specific?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the changes to Django between 1.5 and 1.6 in the [version 1.6 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/).

Possible changes to the template structure include:

- Small change to template syntax (BoundField.label_tag now includes the form’s label_suffix)
- Changes to an admin view (Admin views _changelist_filters GET parameter)
- New rule for raising an exception when rendering a template (If a NoReverseMatch exception is raised from a method when rendering a template, it is not silenced.)
- Changes to `cycle` and `firstof` (Changes to cycle and firstof)

Hopefully you can get a better answer from someone doing a similar transition.

Also, I encourage you to raise any specific issues you have seen to make it easier to answer.